# Iphone: How Write Custom Image Picker With Edit and Multipool selection properties

Tags: iphone, image, ios4, uiscrollview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to Create a view controller just like the image picker controller but:

1) I want to use my application documents folder as my source folder

2) I need to have "edit" button which will allow me to add , remove and change the order of the images

3) I want to be able to select multipool images and on a button click to get an array of the indexes of all the pictures selected

I am new to iphone IOS and thus source code examples are more then welcome :)

Found this tutorial:

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker
```

which is very helpful but it lacks the second and the third property. Since i'm a beginner and self learner, iam having difficulties to add them

Any help is appreciated,

Thank Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get you part of the way there.

Check out the open source project ELCImagePickerController, which allows you to select multiple images at a time:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/03/update-elcimagepickercontroller

[image: A typical ELC image picker screen]

And then you can modify the code to add in "edit" functionality.